# Nested list in Live Script

Tags: matlab

How can I make nested list in the Live Script in MATLAB? I only have the "bulleted list" or the "numbered list", but I'd like to be able to do something like this

[image]

to be able to use it later "Like we saw in 2a) ..."

Do I need to necessarily use LaTeX for such "advanced" features?